# An integral formula involving parabolic cylinder functions (Fourier Transform of parabolic cylinder functions and an exponential function)

Tags: integration, trigonometry, special-functions, fourier-transform

Table of Integrals, Series, and Products (8th edition)(I.S.Gradshteyn,I.M.Ryzhik,Daniel Zwillinger, and Victor Moll) contains the following formula.(Page 852)

7.741 5.

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}\cos(bx)\left(D_{2\nu-\frac{1}{2}}(x)+D_{2\nu-\frac{1}{2}}(-x)\right)\mathrm dx=\frac{ 2^{\frac{1}{4}-2\nu}\pi^{\frac{1}{2}}b^{2\nu-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-\frac{1}{4}b^2}}{\csc((\nu+\frac{1}{4})\pi)}$$
$$\operatorname{Re} \nu>\frac{1}{4}, \quad b>0$$

As far as I've checked, this formula is wrong.

Does anyone know the correct formula?

Comment: This holds (apparently for $\operatorname {Re} \nu > -1/4$ as well, with a conditionally convergent integral):
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2/4} \cos(b x) \hspace {1.5 px}
 (D_{2 \nu - 1/2}(x) + D_{2 \nu + 1/2}(-x)) \, dx =
\sqrt {2 \pi} \hspace {1.5 px} b^{2 \nu - 1/2} e^{-b^2/2}
 \sin \frac {(4 \nu + 1) \pi} 4.$$

Comment: The second parabolic cylinder function is $D_{2v-\frac{1}{2}}(-x)$, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, my bad, I meant
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2/4} \cos(b x) \hspace {1.5 px}
 (D_{2 \nu - 1/2}(x) + D_{2 \nu - 1/2}(-x)) \, dx =
\sqrt {2 \pi} \hspace {1.5 px} b^{2 \nu - 1/2} e^{-b^2/2}
 \sin \frac {(4 \nu + 1) \pi} 4, \\
\operatorname {Re} \nu > -\frac 1 4, \quad b > 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2/2}\cos(bx) [D_{2\nu-1/2}(x)+D_{2\nu-1/2}(-x)]dx
$$
$$
=
\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2/2}\cos(bx)  \frac{2^{\nu+3/4}\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma(3/4-\nu)}e^{-x^2/4}{}_1F_1(-\nu+1/4;1/2;x^2/2)dx
$$
$$
= 
\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{\Gamma(3/4-\nu)}
(2/3)^{\nu+1/4}
e^{-b^2/3}
{}_1F_1(-\nu+1/4;1/2;-\frac{2b^2}{3})
$$
The derivation of that formula is in [vixra:2207.0148](https://vixra.org/abs/2207.0148).

Comment: Some explanation and/or references would be much appreciated. As it is this answer is next to useless.

Comment: @R.J.Mathar You submitted the referenced paper just yesterday. Can you briefly write it out please in your answer?